# Can a slicer display (only display not use) values from a corresponding column within the same table or are there overriding slicers?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Hi Stack Overflow PowerBI/DAX Community,

Tried searching through multiple forums and coming up with ways to go about it but can’t quite find a solution that works perfectly. I did come up with some ideas but unsure if it’s feasible, so let me know your thoughts. Both a screenshot and sample PBIX file from a public OneDrive is provided below for clarity. The file uses Import mode for troubleshooting, but my report is in Direct Query mode (more on that later).

**Description:** My report displays historical data and its pre-selected to display 2 dates as the default view. The table has 2 columns: ‘Day’ representing a number for a day and ‘Date’ the date of that day. Both is in reference to each other (e.g. 0 = 11/06/23, 1 = 11/05/23, etc). The pre-selection requirement must be from the ‘Day’ column because the database updates the data through that column only.

**Issue:** Due to the pre-selection requirement of slicing by the ‘Day’ column, having a date slicer for my end users limits their selection to 2 of 4 dates, but they should have the ability to select from all 4 dates.

**Ideal Solution (Slicer Value Reference):** If I continue to use the slicer with ‘Day’ values (0, 1, 2, 3), is there a way to show the corresponding ‘Date’ values instead? Unbeknownst to the end user, they see only the “dates” but actually slicing the ‘Day’ values, which makes it easy for me so I can keep the default slicer to 2 ‘Day’ values (0 and 1).

**Workaround Solution (Slicer Override):** Have 2 slicers, one for ‘Day’ column and the other for ‘Date’ column, then have my pre-selected ‘Day’ slicer hidden from view. The ‘Date’ slicer is visible and have all 4 dates available that can override the ‘Day’ slicer. I tried to do this using edit interactions, but it doesn’t work that day.

**Unpopular Workaround (‘Day’ value under ‘Date’ value):** Not ideal and haven’t had a chance to fully test it but sounds like it’ll work. Add the ‘Date’ column as a slicer value first, then ‘Day’ column, which becomes acts as the value underneath the ‘Date’ value, then pre-select my ‘Day’ values. The user sees a dropdown arrow for each date, but at least sees the dates.

**Question:** Based off my problem, are either of the first two solutions presented feasible and if so, how? If not, am I stuck trying the third unpopular workaround or do you recommend another method? Again, screenshot and PBIX file link below.

**Comment:** Since my report is through Direct Query mode, I’ve heard others responding to a problem like mines and said to create a separate non-related table, setup a uni-directional relationship cardinality from the non-related table to the ‘Day’ column, then slice against the non-related table. Not sure if that’s the only solution or is there a measure that can cleverly display ‘Date’ values for ‘Day’ values…Again, thank you in advance.

**Public OneDrive of PBIX file:** [Slicer Value Reference or Overriding Slicer.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al_wu2JSnYL4iQXTshmgbx0YEjQV?e=dAHq07)

[image: Sample PBIX image of Slicer Value Reference or Overriding Slicer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Your **Unpopular Workaround (‘Day’ value under ‘Date’ value)** is the best/easiest option and it works. You could rename 'Day' in the Slicer field to 'days ago' and some users may find it useful.</s>
Unfortunately, this option doesn't work as the slicer "remembers" the parent selection as well.

Let me simplify your question - how can I set default 'dynamic' values for slicers?
There isn't a feature for this yet in Power BI. There are one or two custom visuals in the marketplace that claim they do. Look for "[Preselected Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/insiderscoop1611244107840.powerbi_customviz_preselected-slicer?tab=Overview)" in More visuals in the home ribbon, then From AppSource.

One alternative to this, in your case for example, is to have an 'adjusted' date column...

| Day | Date | Adjusted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7-Nov-23 | Today |
| 1 | 6-Nov-23 | Yesterday |
| 2 | 5-Nov-23 | 5-Nov-23 |

And then you use the "adjusted" column for your slicer. I know this won't help you with your DirectQuery but throwing it out there. If this option is appealing, then perhaps see if you can create a 'Mixed' storage mode where you can have DirectQuery and local/imported tables in the same dataset.

Comment: After the daily db/dataset refresh, the "unpopular workaround" did not work. PowerBI kept the old date selected (0-to-old date relationship retention issue?) and deselected the new date that now relates to Day 0 and/or 1. Not sure if this is a db-level issue since all data rows referring to Day 0 for example, are deleted and restored on a daily basis to "refresh" the data for the day. PowerBI is somehow keeping the old 0-to-old date relationship alive until there's manual intervention from an end user...regardless, your idea of the mixed storage maybe my best bet...if I can figure it out.

Comment: Apologies - I've done further testing and indeed, the "Unpopular workaround" doesn't work as the slicer keeps track of the parent selection as well as the child. I'll update the answer above to reflect this. I've suggested in the answer above a custom visual that will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test and suggesting a custom visual. Trying to get it to work, but looks like it needs a measure of sorts to use the pre-selection and another third technical measure to exclude from the list?...or something like that. I've posted this same question on the PowerBI Fabric forums (https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Slicer-Value-Reference-or-Overriding-Slicer/m-p/3519028#M1162382) and got an interesting answer that I'm still trying to understand the concept behind it, but thought I'd share it with you too. Thank you for always being so supportive.